# Detailed overview over old exchange rate

Tags: historical-trade-data

I would like to create a detailed overview about the exchange rate of bitcoins over the last months. Unfortunately, all I can find are lists with one value per day, but I would like to have much more detail (one value per hour at last).

Is such a detailed list available somewhere on the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best sites I've found is [Bitcoincharts.com](http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/bitstampUSD#rg120ztgCzm1g10zm2g25zv). The charts allow you to see Bitcoin prices from its entire history or down to the hour. It allows you to view the prices on different exchanges and markets too.

Comment: And it has an API for historic data. See section "Historic Trade Data" at [bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/).