# Exchange currency trade history

Tags: exchanges, raw-data, historical-trade-data

I am looking for datasets of trade history, which contains the following information: date-time, buy/sell, price. The currency pair and exchange is not important.

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9776/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22769/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/36088/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/35706/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/748/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22989/5406

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try my website [cryptodatasets.com](http://cryptodatasets.com) It has free raw data and sampled data from Bitfinex and HitBtc (currently).

Answer (score 0):

I found a website called [CryptoDataDownload](https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/), but I'm not certain if it's precisely what you're searching for. But still, check it. Probably you can find some useful info for yourself.